# Directory appears as child but doesn't exist

Tags: c, linux

Using C/C++, I tried creating a directory (using mkdir(path, 0777)) and then a file inside that directory.
The error that appears when creating the file is "No such file or directory".

The directory is created (inside /etc/tool in this case) but when I try to ls the directory, the same message appears. Cd works.

In the image bellow the directory after being created is shown, as well as several things I tried such as manually creating the directory and changing permissions.

I have no clue about what is happening or how to describe it in a short enough sentence to get any relevant information from google/stackoverflow.

[image: CMD image of several attempts to discover what is happening]

Any ideas on how to proceed or where to look for more clues would be appreciated.

Comment: Should be: `ls /etc/tools/remotehosts`. Note the extra `s` at the end.

Comment: Next time, please don't post images for text output/code - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: While it's good to see the directories and files, it would be even better to see a [mcve] of the code itself.

Comment: In fact idk why but either the autocomplete screwed me over or I managed to miss every S, I will read the reasoning, and post a minimal reproducible example ASAP. Thank you both.

Comment: Since Digres gave out an answer, I marked it as correct and explained the problem in a comment. The s was the giveaway symptom of my codes' bug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are looking for /etc/tool/remotehosts directory

try this

```
ls /etc/tool/remotehosts/
```

Comment: The problem was that the code in a very deep function was cutting the last character. Kaylum was correct. Some Programmer dude, I will add "create a minimal reproducible example" to my debugging set! Thank you all.